# how to disable the output in powershell startup

Tags: powershell, windows-terminal

Every time when I open a powershell, the following content is displayed

```bsh
PowerShell 7.0.3
Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

https://aka.ms/powershell
Type'help' to get help.
```

What parameters should I set to close it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use the -Nologo optio as stated [here](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff629472.aspx):

> -NoLogo Starts the PowerShell console without displaying the copyright banner.

> For example, you can start Windows PowerShell in no-logo mode (meaning the logo banner is turned off) by using the startup command powershell -nologo

Answer (score 1):

Given that you state Windows-Terminal, I assume you want to know how to alter the Windows Terminal App to not show the copyright banner.

In Windows Terminal, press the down arrow next to the plus, go to settings.

A Notepad opens up with your config.

Locate the following line below your profile:

```
"commandline": "powershell.exe"
```

and change it to:

```
"commandline": "powershell.exe -nologo"
```

Save the file and exit.

Now close windows terminal and start it again, and the banner will be gone.